# Twilio calls integration to ios app without server app

Tags: ios, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

This must be a silly question, but is there any way to make calls btw two iOS apps without server app mentioned in Twilio tutorials. Tell me please what server app does and is there any way to perform such tasks on front end instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The server is required to generate an access token for your users to get access to the Twilio service.

You also need to host some TwiML to tell Twilio what to do with calls when you make them.

If you are not interested in running a server, however, you are in luck. Just recently, [Twilio launched Functions](https://www.twilio.com/functions), a serverless environment for you to deploy code to. With a Twilio Function, you can use Node.js to generate your access tokens for your users and you won't have to host the code yourself, it will all be on the Twilio platform.

Check out [Twilio Functions in your console](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/functions/manage) and take a look at the [Node.js quickstart application](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/client-quickstart-node) for the iOS Twilio Programmable Voice SDK which should give you an idea of how to use Node for your application within Functions. I'm sure there'll be tutorials and blog posts coming out. Also, check out this [video on how to create access tokens for your apps with Twilio Functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lrdYBLEk60).

Let me know if that helps at all.